# Argument of complex function - realtion to signum function

Tags: complex-numbers

I searched all internet and I can't get my answer.
Please, can you explain how $\mathrm{sgn}(x)$ found its way to solution of this problem ?

$$\mathrm{Arg}[ \frac{w_0^2}{wi (w_0 + iw)}]$$

I need to calculate this expression, where $w_0$ is a parameter. I know the result. It includes $\mathrm{sgn}(w)$, but I can't figure out how it was calculated. Please help :)
I know the basic formula,
$$\arg(z)=\arctan(\mathrm{Im}(z)/\mathrm{Re}(z)).$$

Comment: And the result is...?

Comment: Result is:    (Pi/2)sign(w)-arctan(w/w0)

Comment: **Very** weird. $\mathrm{sgn}(z) = z/|z|$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function#Complex_signum) can be $\not\in\Bbb R$ while $\mathrm{Arg}$ takes real values.  Also, $\arctan$ of the **complex** number $w/w_0$?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely **wrong**. If $w = w_0\ne 0$,
$$
\frac{w_0^2}{wi(w_0 + iw)} = \frac{w_0^2}{w_0 i(w_0 + iw_0)} =
\frac{1}{i(1 + i)} = -\frac{1 + i}2
$$
has constant argument while
$$
(\pi/2)\mathrm{sgn}(w) - \arctan(w/w_0) =
(\pi/2)\mathrm{sgn}(w_0) - \arctan(1) = (\pi/2)(w_0/|w_0|) - \pi/4
$$
depends of the argument of $w_0$!

Idea for the search of a (correct) solution: as the (multivalued) argument of the product is sum of arguments:
$$
\mathrm{Arg}\left(\frac{w_0^2}{wi(w_0 + iw)}\right) =
2\mathrm{Arg}(w_0) - \mathrm{Arg}(w) - \mathrm{Arg}(i) -
\mathrm{Arg}(w_0 + iw).
$$

Comment: right. And $Arg(z)=arg(z)+2k\pi$ and $arg(z)=arctan_4(Re(z),\; Im(z))$, that is $arctan$ taken over all $4$ quadrants